# regex matches uppercase letters, spaces, & symbol and apostrophes from begining of string to first comma

Tags: php, regex, uppercase

I'm trying this regex, but along with uppercase it matches lowercase somehow.

```
preg_match("/^([A-Z&\s\']+),/i", $line, $match);
```

Any ideas where is my mistake?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you make an example of what you want to match and how it fails

Comment: Unable to reproduce... can you provide screenshots and/or examples?

Comment: where is the rest of the php for it, do you have the `\i` flag?

Comment: I'm trying to match uppercase words with symbols from beginning of string to first comma. But it matches lowercase words too.

Comment: preg_match("/^([A-Z&\s\']+),/i", $line, $match);

Comment: Works for me...I think you want to remove the /i which makes it case insensitive.

Comment: I'd also see Bart's answer about the ending anchor...

Comment: it works fine even without `$` anchor. `preg_match("/^([A-Z&\s']+),/", "A&' F,M&' F,fgh", $m)`

Comment: RudyTheHunter, "i" caused problem, thanks!

Comment: See it [**working here**](https://regex101.com/r/cH4tU7/1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the case insensitive modifier `/i`:

```
preg_match('/^([A-Z&\s\']+),/', $line, $match);
                             ^
```

Otherwise, the `[A-Z]` range matches both `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` ranges.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z&\s\']+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters (`A-Z`), a literal `&`, whitespace (`\s`) or a literal `'`
- `,` - a comma